# Get large Facebook page profile picture using graph api & php

Tags: php, graph

I'm trying to get large page profile picture using graph api and php, and I did it the following way:

```
$getBigImage = get_headers('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$PID.'/picture?type=large&access_token='.$this->token.'',1);
$data['fbBigImage'] = $getBigImage['Location'];
```

My problem starts when I get sometimes error of:

```
[13-Sep-2015 08:19:37 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  get_headers(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in line 252
[13-Sep-2015 08:19:37 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  get_headers(https://graph.facebook.com/1437355116498102/picture?type=large&amp;access_token=***): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in line 252
```

I need to use another way or good alternative to the get_headers since it's sometimes fails (most of the times it works, but I need something to work with 100% of the cases)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is caused by network problems. By the looks of it, it can't resolve the domain name. If that is the case, you would have to "keep trying" until your connection to the internet is restored.

Comment: I did 2 retries, it's still not a way to make sure it'll work.

Comment: Have you tried it with a user id instead of using a page id ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to check whether it's a network problem or not, you could try running:

`<?php
print_r(get_headers('http://google.com'));`

As Google is the international connectivity tester ( :P ) you can make sure if it's on the network or not.

Also, do you use some proxy? (If yes) Is it set up on the system or in each browser?